# R model variable score

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict, coefficients

I built a linear regression model in R and tried to get the contribution amount (not the coefficient) of each of the explanatory variables (independent variables) (i.e. x1, x2, x3). Question:

1. How can I get such amount for the fitted data. That is numeric value contributed by each x (x1, x2, x3) for each observation.
2. How can I get the same amount for new (unseen) data

```
df = data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)
mod = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `summary(mod)`? what do you mean by 'contribution amount'?

Comment: no. Let's say y = 10, of the 10 what number did x1, x2 and x3 contributed?

Comment: Refer to @G5W answer on how `predict` actually calculates the prediction. If you are referring to y as a response value then it is vital to understand the model is finding the coefficients which will minimise the sum of squared residuals `(y obs - y pred)^2`. Once you have your coefficient estimates, you can multiply them with x1,x2,x3 to obtain the value which the model predicts given the predictors. The predicted value will not be an exact match due to both irreducible and reducible error. Introduction to Statistical Learning is a great book to learn linear regression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ali suggested, I think that `summary(mod)` *does* answer your question. Let me give a bit more explanation. Since you do not provide your data, I will use the built-in iris data as an example.

```
mod = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris[,1:4])
summary(mod)$coefficients
               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   1.8559975 0.25077711  7.400984 9.853855e-12
Sepal.Width   0.6508372 0.06664739  9.765380 1.199846e-17
Petal.Length  0.7091320 0.05671929 12.502483 7.656980e-25
Petal.Width  -0.5564827 0.12754795 -4.362929 2.412876e-05
```

Notice the column labeled "Estimate". Those are the model coefficients. Just to be really explicit, let's go through an an example of how they relate to the prediction.

```
iris[1,]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

predict(mod, newdata=iris[1,])
       1 
5.015416
```

OK, so if we predict the first row using the model, we get the answer 5.015416. How did that come from the coefficients?

```
 1.8559975 +            ## Intercept
 0.6508372 * 3.5 +      ## Sepal.Width
 0.7091320 * 1.4 +      ## Petal.Length
-0.5564827 * 0.2        ## Petal.Width
[1] 5.015416
```